# Mysql is not working correctly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello Stackoverflow,

I was trying to connect to my MySQL database through Coda 2. I connected, created a database called 'database1' (for example), then I tried to create a table called 'user', but I get this error:

```
MySQL said: Table 'user' is read only
```

I was surprised because it had worked previously with other databases long time ago. I went to my xampp files, //xampp/mysql/data/database1/ and then I found out that user.ibd is there alone. So I first tried to change the properties of the files by disabling read-only. The problem is that when I  did that, close  the properties windows, and opened again I would get the read-only check box on. So I gave up on that. So I said ok, I will just create the database from my server instead. So I when to phpmyadmin, I see that database1 is created but there is no table called 'user'. So I try to create a table and I get this error:

```
#1813 - Tablespace for table '`database1`.`user`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

I then I found out I cannot even do much with phpmyadmin from my server. I tried reinstalling xampp, but it was impossible for me to remove the origianal because it was "already" in use. Please help me and thank you!

EDIT: I can apparently create databases but not tables. Just to clear that up.

Comment: Did you try `DROP TABLE user` and then creating it?

Comment: I tried that but it says unknown table called user

Comment: You made sure in CLI you specified `use database1;` first, right?  What does `SHOW TABLES;` output?

Comment: Nothing is outputter when using: **use database1;
SHOW TABLES;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using CLI and logged into mysql and create a new database and a table. If it's working, there's something wrong with your phpmyadmin not mysql. Make sure you logged in as the same user (whom have root privileges) when creating the database and table.

Comment: I tried CLI and I still had the read only problem. I cannot login with the username I use on Coda 2 on my server. I guess that account (hostname is %) can only be used outside the server. I use the root account on the server (hostname localhost).